# Usage of perfect infinitives

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive

"he was believed to have killed the king but was later acquitted of those charges" -
is the *perfect infinitive* "to have killed" used correctly in this sentence ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Here is a definition and example of "believed to be" from [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/someone-something-is-believed-to-be):

> (1) **used for saying that it is the general opinion of most people that something is true although it has not been proved**
>
> *A third man is missing and is believed to have been taken into police custody*.

Comment: Yes. But what I really want to know is whether it is also correct if the principal verb(he "was" believed) is in past tense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the perfect is valid used that way. See the example at this link to Google books:

[Student's Intro to English Grammar "Perfect"](https://tinyurl.com/ybhqm4gx)

iiia "She is said to have spoken perfect Greek."